# Facing Issue at the time of Creating template DB on Plan section in Odoo SaaS for Odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo, saas, odoo-11

I am facing an Exception when I create Plan in Odoo SaaS. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Odoo 11 Community Edition, Postgres Database.
In this above description I create a server in SaaS after that I make Plan then simply save and press the Button Create template DB after that this exception is come.

Please suggest me the solution how to handle this. I follow this documentation link as reference.
[Odoo Saas Tool kit](https://odoo-saas-tools.readthedocs.io/en/10.0/setup/install.html) and facing following Exceptions at the time of creating Plan in SaaS.

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdf70915f60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='s1.odoo.local', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /saas_server/new_database (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdf70915f60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 651, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 693, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 937, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 938, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo-saas-tools/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 410, in create_template_button
    return self.create_template()
  File "/home/shivam/Videos/odoo-11.0/odoo-saas-tools/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 428, in create_template
    res = requests.Session().send(req, **req_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='s1.odoo.local', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /saas_server/new_database (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdf70915f60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Didn't find any clue regarding this please help me.

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue,have you solved it ?

Comment: Use s1.odoo.local:8069 in URL tab.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it is sure that the script is trying to resolve `s1.odoo.local` which is not in your `dns` or `hosts` entry, so you should enter this host entry in your `/etc/hosts` file with the IP address of the hosts you want to resolve this domain to. For example,

127.0.0.1 s1.odoo.local

append this line at the end of your `/etc/hosts` file, replacing `127.0.0.1` with your intended host IP.
Or you can setup your script so that IP address is used instead of domain name like `odoo.local`

From official documentation:

> If you run odoo locally, add domains you are going to use to
>   /etc/hosts. E.g.
>   127.0.0.1 odoo.local # portal
>
> 127.0.0.1 s1.odoo.local # server
>
> 127.0.0.1 t1.odoo.local # template
>
> 127.0.0.1 t2.odoo.local # template
>
> 127.0.0.1 client-x.odoo.local
>
> 127.0.0.1 client-y.odoo.local
>
> 127.0.0.1 client-z.odoo.local

Just follow the documentation! You linked with your question, but you didn't even followed it.

Comment: All the steps I follow according to the documentation of SaaS but still it is not working. Please suggest me the other way to resolve this issuee

Comment: `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` This message ensures that in this case, the `name` is not resolved by dns server. If your hosts file contained IP for that host `s1.odoo.local`, it would have been resolved.